# Splitting a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string: multiple characters such as `!!!` , `??`, `...` denote the end of the sentence so I want anything after this to be on a new line e.g. sentence `hey.. hello split !!! example me.` should be turned into:

```
hey..
hello split !!!
example me.
```

What I tried:

```
String myStr= "hey.. hello split !!! example me.";
String [] split = myStr.split("(?<=\\.{2,})");
```

This works fine when I have multiple dots but doesn't work for anything else, I can't add exclamation marks to this expression too `"(?<=[\\.{2,}!{2,}])`. This splits after each dot and exclamation. Is there any way to combine those ?
Ideally I wanted the app to split after a SINGLE dot too (anything that denotes the end of the sentence) but I don't think this is possible in a single pass...Thanks

Comment: Do you want to split after a single punctuation, or only 2+ of them?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Just do like this,</strike>

```
String [] split = myStr.split("(?<=([?!.])\\1+)");
```

oir

```
String [] split = myStr.split("(?<=([?!.])\\1{1,99})");
```

It captures the first character from the list `[?.!]` and expects the same character to be present one or more times. If yes, then  the splitting should occur next to this.

or

```
String[] split = s.split("(?<=\\.{2,}+)|(?<=\\?{2,}+)|(?<=!{2,}+)");
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/5YuNyE)

Comment: [`"(?<=([?!.])\\1+)"`](https://ideone.com/wfkGQU) and [`"(?<=([?!.])\\1{1,99})"`](https://ideone.com/xSaCYq) will throw an exception: *Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length*

Comment: thanks, check now.. @WiktorStribiżew I thought, if this `(?<=\\.{2,})` is possible then `(?<=([?!.])\\1+)` also be possible. Crazy java.

Comment: The problem is in the backreference whose length is not known from the start.

Comment: @Avinash Raj perfect, thanks ! out of curiosity if I also had to check for `!?` how could we alter this: `(?<=!\\?{1,}+)` throws  an exception: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length

Comment: @Frugo did you check my answer.

Comment: @Avinash Raj yes. It does not split after `!?`

Comment: you mean this `s.split("(?<=\\.{2,}+)|(?<=\\?{2,}+)|(?<=!{2,}+)|(?<=!\\?)");`

Comment: You can use `s.split("(?<=[.?!]{2,}+)")`

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I wanted the app to split after a SINGLE dot too (anything that denotes the end of the sentence)

To do this first you have to lay down as to what cases are you considering as **end of sentence**. Multiple special symbols are not standard form of ending a sentence (as per my knowledge).

But if you are keeping in mind the nefarious users or some casual mistakes ending up making special symbols look like end of sentence then at least make a list of such cases and then proceed.

For your situation here where you want to split the string on multiple special symbols. **Lookbehind** won't be of much help because as Wiktor noted

> The problem is in the backreference whose length is not known from the start.

So we need to find that **zero-width** where splitting needs to be done. And following regex does the same.

**Regex:**

- `(?<=[.!?])(?=[^.!?])`  <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP8hT8/2)**</kbd> <kbd>**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/pSKQlA)**</kbd>
- `(?<=[.!?]) (?=[^.!?])` <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP8hT8/1)**</kbd> <kbd>**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/fIr48r)**</kbd>

Note the `space` between two assertions in second regex.If you want to consume the preceding `space` when start next line.

**Explanation:**

- This will split on the **zero-width** where it's preceded by special and not succeeded by it.

> `hey..¦ hello split !!!¦ example me.` ( ¦ denotes the zero-width)

Comment: Thanks, I like how short it is

Answer (score 0):

A look behind, with a negative look to prevent split within the group:

```
String[] lines = s.split("(?<=[?!.]{2,3})(?![?!.])");
```

---

Some test code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String s = "hey..hello split !!!example me.";
    String[] lines = s.split("(?<=[?!.]{2,3})(?![?!.])");
    Arrays.stream(lines).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
hey..
hello split !!!
example me.
```